# Set and animate Fill of Rectangle inside Button's ContentTemplate

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, button, windows-phone

I work with WP7 project.
I have styled buttons with a number of ContentTemplates defined.
Those ContentTeplates include Shapes (for simplicity let's use Rectangle):

```
<Button x:Name="button1" 
        Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}" 
        ContentTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate1}">
</Button>

<Button x:Name="button2" 
        Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}" 
        ContentTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate2}">
</Button>
...

<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1">
    <Rectangle Height="100" Width="100" Fill="{QUESTION_HERE}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

I want Fill property of Rectangle to be

1. equal to Foreground color of hosting Button
2. changed accordingly when button is pressed or disabled

How can I achieve that?

---

### My not-so-good solution

At WinRT I use RelativeSource approach wich works quite well:

```
Fill="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
```

Unfortunately at WP that fails to work. The reason for that is ContentPresenter at WP doesn't have ForegroundProperty while at WinRT it does.

So I have tried to define my own attached DP at ContentPresenter and use it in Button template:

*Button.Template >> ContentControl.Template >>*

```
<ContentPresenter 
    local:FrameworkElementExtensions.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
```

You know when I define that DP at ContentPresenter RelativeSource binding starts working.

But the bad side is when Button is pressed, Rectangle's Fill is updated with a few milliseconds delay.
**That doesn't look well and I seek better solution**.

Answer (score 0):

**This will work in SL5 or WPF**

Relative source approach will work OK if you go to the `Button` instead of the `ContentPresenter`.

```
Fill="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button}}"
```

You can also define `AncestorType=ButtonBase` if you need the same template to work with other types of buttons, e.g. `RepeatButton`, `ToggleButton` etc.

### EDIT:

**This is a hack for SL3/4 or WP7**

Put a `TextBlock` in your `DataTemplate` and bind to its foreground.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock x:Name="ForegroundProvider" Width="0" Height="0" Opacity="0"/>
        <Path Fill="{Binding Foreground, ElementName=ForegroundProvider}" ..../>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

It's ugly, but that's WP7... :(

Comment: 1. Unfortunately RelativeSource FindAncestor is not supported in WP7 (only Self and TemplatedParent are) 
2. I'm afraid Button.Foreground is not the right property to bind to. If you look at Button Template you see button states change Foreground of ContentControl holding Button contents, not Button itself

Comment: **1.** Missed the fact that it's WP7... See edited answer. **2.** In that case (and under SL4/5 or WPF with the same template) use `AncestorType=ContentControl`.

Comment: Thank you for your time.

Unfortunately Textblock Foreground hack doesn't follow button press and disable states. When I press button, its background and foreground change. I do want those changes to be reflected in Shape within Content. Otherwise I would've used hardcoded colors.

Comment: And just in case - I want that to work for Windows Phone 7.5 which is Silverlight 4, not Silverlight 3. AFAIK SL4 doesn't have FindAndestor too

Comment: Sorry, I always mess up what version got what features, there are too many versions for me :). Re-edited the answer.

Comment: Regarding your second comment - try using `TextElement.Foreground` in the binding. I'm not at my dev machine so haven't tested it.

Comment: TextElement.Foreground does not help